# How do I disable 'hold left click to trigger right click' in Ubuntu Dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock

When I hold left click on an application icon in Ubuntu dock It show right click menu options. How can I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you cannot change that without editing source code.

This behavior apparently is inherited from the Gnome Shell Dock. When the Ubuntu Dock is disabled, you still get to see a dock (aka the Dash) in the overview, i.e., the view you get when clicking the Activities button. Also there, a long click on an icon will reveal the right-click options. Thus, this is standard behavior of Gnome Shell, the desktop environment Ubuntu is build upon.

As no settings related to this behavior are exposed, one likely must edit the source code of Gnome Shell to change that behavior.

Comment: thats a nice explanation.. can you include some ideas on is there a way to edit source code or how to know which file have code related to it..

Comment: @PRATAP, I surely would if I were a system expert with good developper skills or if I had plenty of time ;)